# Object allocation inline on the stack

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, object, stack

What does that mean when it says 'object allocation inline on the stack'?

Especially the 'inline' bit

Comment: what is the context of the sentence?

Answer (score 3):

It means that all the data for the object is allocated on the stack, and will be popped off when the current method terminates.

The alternative (which occurs in C# and Java, or if you're using a pointer in C++) is to have a reference or pointer on the stack, which refers to the object data which is allocated on the heap.

I think the "inline" here just means "as part of the stack frame for this method" as opposed to existing separately from the method.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you know what the stack is, right? If you declare a function in, say, C:

```
int foo() {
    int bar = 42;
    return bar;
}
```

When the function is called, some space is created for information about the function on the stack, and the integer `bar` is allocated there as well. When the function returns, everything in that stack frame is deallocated.

Now, in C++:

```
class A {
    int a;
    int b;
    A(int x, int y) {
       a = x;
       b = y;
    }
    ~A() {  // destructor
       cout << "A(" << a << "," << b << ") being deleted!" << endl;
    }
}

void foo() {
    A on_the_stack(1,2);
    A *on_the_heap = new A(3,4);        
}
```

In languages like Java, all objects are allocated on the heap (unless the compiler does some sort of optimization). But in some languages like C++, the class objects can go right on the stack just like `int`s or `float`s. Memory from the heap is not used unless you explicitly call `new`. Note that our `on_the_heap` object never gets deallocated (by calling `delete` on it), so it causes a memory leak. The `on_the_stack` object, on the other hand, is automatically deallocated when the function returns, and will have its destructor called prior to doing so.